# Spark : Understanding Executor Metrics in spark application (JVMHeapMemory, OnHeapExecutionMemory, OnHeapStorageMemory, OnHeapUnifiedMemory)

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand some of the memory related metric values reported in the executor metrics from every executor in an apache spark application. Specifically these

1. JVMHeapMemory
2. OnHeapExecutionMemory
3. OnHeapStorageMemory
4. OnHeapUnifiedMemory

As per the [documentation in the Spark monitoring page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) these metrics should be the peak memory values but the value that i see in an spark job are as below

21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.JVMHeapMemory, value=260976800
21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.OnHeapExecutionMemory, value=0
21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.OnHeapStorageMemory, value=561315
21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.OnHeapUnifiedMemory, value=561315

21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.JVMOffHeapMemory, value=241239736
21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.OffHeapStorageMemory, value=0
21/09/25 13:25:06 INFO metrics: type=GAUGE, name=application_1632317519942_0618.driver.ExecutorMetrics.OffHeapUnifiedMemory, value=0

As per my understanding JVM On Heap memory should be = OnHeapExecutionMemory + OnHeapStorageMemory + Reserved memory (~300MB) + User memory (0.25 * (heap memory - reserved memory))

But as you can see the on heap execution and storage memory is much smaller compared to the total jvm on heap memory. And i would like to understand this better. Can someone please explain this?